# View controller getting duplicate instantiation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

This should be pretty straight forward.

When I use the navigation controller to segue from my root view to my 2nd view, the 2nd view loads fine.
The 2nd view creates a timer in "viewDidLoad" to call a method "updateData" periodically.

Maybe I'm not understanding the system here, but when I go back to root and forward again to the 2nd view, I'm getting a completely new instance of the 2nd view controller, which makes a new timer (updateData is getting called twice as frequently).

This is not correct default behavior is it? How can I show the first instance of the 2nd view controller instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Yes this is the correct default behavior. Segues ALWAYS instantiate new controllers. If you don't want a new one, don't use segues.

Comment: Oh, ok! That sure saved me hours of confusion. Persistent objects shouldn't be properties of view controllers, I take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily true that persistent objects shouldn't be properties of view controller. You can create a property for your second controller (in the root view controller), and only instantiate it the first time you push it. Because you have a strong pointer to it, it won't be deallocated when you go back to the first controller, and your timer will continue to operate.

```
- (IBAction)goToSecondView {
    if (!self.secondViewController) { // secondViewController is a strong property
        self.secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"]; 
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head: In your second view controllers deallocate method, you should stop the timer of the "updateData", as it is not properly deallocated. Try that!

```
[self.timer invalidate];
```

Comment: That would work, except I want the timer to run continuously. Should I make the timer a property of something other than the 2nd view controller?

Comment: I think it would save a lot of headache for the 2nd view not to be deallocated when it disappears. Maybe that's not standard?

Comment: Yeah that's not standard. A better way would be to put the timer on the main view controller if you need to.